# Union Order By using different field SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im trying to sort below query by using Order By. However when im using MonthYear field the output result display as below which not sort accordingly by latest year and month.

Order By MonthYear Output.

```
 MonthYear
    2017/9
    2017/8
    2017/7
    2017/6
    2017/5
    2017/4
    2017/10
```

So I want to try by order by year and month but i cant do it since another query after union all line has different field which is a.created_year. Is there any way I can do it?

```
SELECT      CONVERT(varchar, A.YEAR) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar, A.MONTH)AS MonthYear
FROM            PAY_Previous AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         EMPLOYEE_BADGE AS B ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = B.EMPLOYEE_NO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         V_EMPLOYEE_PROFILES AS C ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = C.EMPLOYEE_NO
WHERE   A.EMPLOYEE_NO = '710049' AND      A.FREQUENCY = 2 and (day(getdate())>=28 or month(getdate()) > a.Month or YEAR(getdate()) > A.YEAR )



UNION ALL-

SELECT       CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(A.CREATED_DATE)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar, A.MONTH) AS MonthYear
FROM            PAY_Current AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         EMPLOYEE_BADGE AS B ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = B.EMPLOYEE_NO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         V_EMPLOYEE_PROFILES AS C ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = C.EMPLOYEE_NO
WHERE   A.EMPLOYEE_NO = '710049'AND  A.FREQUENCY = 2  and (day(getdate())>=28 or month(getdate()) > a.Month or YEAR(getdate()) > A.CREATED_DATE )

ORDER BY YEAR(A.CREATED_DATE) DESC ,A.MONTH DESC
```

Expected Output

```
 MonthYear
    2017/10
    2017/9
    2017/8
    2017/7
    2017/6
    2017/5
    2017/4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the data numeric until the last moment, then convert just the smallest list for presentation, and this leave the numeric columns available for ordering the result.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, d.[YEAR]) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar, d.[MONTH]) AS MonthYear
FROM 
    SELECT
            A.[YEAR] , A.[MONTH]
    FROM PAY_Previous AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE_BADGE AS B ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = B.EMPLOYEE_NO
    LEFT OUTER JOIN V_EMPLOYEE_PROFILES AS C ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = C.EMPLOYEE_NO
    WHERE A.EMPLOYEE_NO = '710049'
    AND A.FREQUENCY = 2
    AND (DAY(GETDATE()) >= 28
    OR MONTH(GETDATE()) > a.Month
    OR YEAR(GETDATE()) > A.YEAR)

    UNION

    SELECT
            YEAR(A.CREATED_DATE) [Year] , A.[MONTH]
    FROM PAY_Current AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE_BADGE AS B ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = B.EMPLOYEE_NO
    LEFT OUTER JOIN V_EMPLOYEE_PROFILES AS C ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = C.EMPLOYEE_NO
    WHERE A.EMPLOYEE_NO = '710049'
    AND A.FREQUENCY = 2
    AND (DAY(GETDATE()) >= 28
    OR MONTH(GETDATE()) > a.Month
    OR YEAR(GETDATE()) > A.CREATED_DATE)
) d
ORDER BY d.[YEAR] DESC, d.[MONTH] DESC
```

btw: Both "YEAR" and "MONTH" are terms used by T-SQL and it is not a good idea to use them as columns names.

IF, you need the result in a form that can reliably be re-ordered, then perhaps you could consider using a leading zero for the month number. e.g.

```
CONVERT(varchar(4), d.[YEAR]) + '/' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), d.[MONTH]),2) AS MonthYear
```

Which would look like this (and sort correctly)

```
2017/10
2017/04
2017/03
2017/02
2017/01
2016/10
2016/05
```

Comment: For pay_current table , you use a.[year] , it should be a. created_date.

Comment: Right, I fixed that thanks. I trust you follow the general suggestion even without that correction.

Comment: Great, please `Accept` by clicking the tick. This signifies to others that tere is a solution helping both those looking for answers, and also helps those looking for questions still to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having a sort problem because you are using Created_Date to sort, but you are using different fields for MonthYear between statements.

Try this:

```
select MonthYear from (
    SELECT      CONVERT(varchar, A.YEAR) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar, A.MONTH)AS MonthYear, A.YEAR yr, A.MONTH mon
    FROM            PAY_Previous AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             EMPLOYEE_BADGE AS B ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = B.EMPLOYEE_NO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             V_EMPLOYEE_PROFILES AS C ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = C.EMPLOYEE_NO
    WHERE   A.EMPLOYEE_NO = '710049' AND      A.FREQUENCY = 2 and (day(getdate())>=28 or month(getdate()) > a.Month or YEAR(getdate()) > A.YEAR )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT       CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(A.CREATED_DATE)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar, A.MONTH) AS MonthYear. YEAR(A.CREATED_DATE)) yr, CONVERT(varchar, A.MONTH) mon
    FROM            PAY_Current AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             EMPLOYEE_BADGE AS B ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = B.EMPLOYEE_NO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             V_EMPLOYEE_PROFILES AS C ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = C.EMPLOYEE_NO
    WHERE   A.EMPLOYEE_NO = '710049'AND  A.FREQUENCY = 2  and (day(getdate())>=28 or month(getdate()) > a.Month or YEAR(getdate()) > A.CREATED_DATE )
    )x

ORDER BY yr DESC, mon DESC
```